# Loading External JS and CSS for one component

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack

I have an Angular 4 app where I use a js and css file for only one component. All of the docs I see recommend putting these files in Index.html, but I don't want to load them on every route, just the component they are used for. The files are sitting in dist folder with other bundled js and are being copied from another folder by webpack.

Comment: Is `import` statement not working for you?

Comment: how would import work with a random js file? It isn't a module

Comment: You can still do it. I don't see any problem.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested by LazyLoad.

Check out [Routing and Lazy loading @NgModules](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter/wiki/Routing-and-Lazy-loading-@NgModules) or this [Lazy Loading a Module](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/modules/lazy-loading-module.html) tutorial.

Comment: It is a component, not a module. Would I have to load the file at the module level?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sass then you can directly import any css files from its package
e.g in example.component.scss file add this

```
@import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

Answer (score 0):

For JS files you must implement the AfterViewInit lifecycle hook and here import your files, for example:

**test.component.ts**

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss']
})
export class TestComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  public ngAfterViewInit() {
    require('path/to/your/script.js');
  }
}
```

and for CSS files, import them in your scss file, like here:

**test.component.scss**

```
@import '~path/to/your/external/style.min.css';
```

Comment: using the ngAfterViewInit() does not load the js file.

Comment: make you sure that you write the correct path. are you using webpack?

Comment: yea, I tried the location before and after packing, nothing

Comment: do you want to import the script from node_modules?

Comment: I actually got it to work, the issue is that this js file loads other js/css files (ckeditor) and this is all done with SSR. More work is needed sadly I think :/